# How to append text to outgoing emails in qmail?

Tags: email

I would like to append automatic text to all outgoing emails from my Qmail server. Is it possible and with what tools/scripts/patches ? I would like to avoid patching Qmail and prefer to use some specific tool or script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ornl.gov/lists/mailing-lists/qmail/2002/09/msg00440.html provides one way to do it - sadly by patching.

However, note the multiple caveats with this approach.  Also, there are many indications that this sort of thing is hard to do in qmail (no specific tool or script) because it's "not a good idea".  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: +1 for not answering the question